# What is ServiceLoader and how is it used?

Tags: java, serviceloader

I came across [the documentation of `ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and am unclear as to what use cases it suits.

When would one use `ServiceLoader`?

Answer (score 8):

You use ServiceLoader when you want your program to have a “plugin” functionality.  When you want to allow people to customize your application by adding jar files to the classpath which contain implementations of a specific subset of functionality, you can use a ServiceLoader to look for those implementations in the classpath.

ServiceLoader is itself an implementation of the [jar SPI specification](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider), which has been around for a long time.  (I believe it was introduced in Java 1.3.)

Java SE already uses it for exactly that purpose in a lot of places, including:

- additional charsets via [CharsetProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html)
- additional filesystems via [FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) (see [FileSystems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html))
- additional file content type analyzers via [FileTypeDetector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html) (see [Files.probeContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)))
- additional preferences implementations via [PreferencesFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/prefs/PreferencesFactory.html) (see [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html))
- custom ResourceBundle.Control via [ResourceBundleControlProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/ResourceBundleControlProvider.html)
- All subclasses of [LocaleServiceProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html):

  - additional calendars via [CalendarDataProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/CalendarDataProvider.html) and [CalendarNameProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/CalendarNameProvider.html)
  - additional currency via [CurrencyNameProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/CurrencyNameProvider.html)
  - additional locales via [LocaleNameProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleNameProvider.html)
  - additional timezones via [TimeZoneNameProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/spi/TimeZoneNameProvider.html)
- additional image formats via [IIORegistry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/IIORegistry.html)
- additional printers via [PrintServiceLookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html)
- custom scripting engines via [ScriptEngineFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory.html)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes, ServiceLoader was introduced in 1.6 as a convenient way to accomplish what the jar specification had already documented for many years prior.  Before ServiceLoader, one would have to do it manually with something like `classLoader.getResources("/META-INF/services/" + spiClass.getName())`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the principle ["Inversion of Control"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)?

Java implemented it by `ServiceLoader`. The class is designed to locate implementation classes of an interface on the classpath. You pass in a service interface, you get an implementation(s) of that service.

You might find a good practical example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/play-with-java-serviceloader-forget-about-dependen).

---

*P.S: Even though it's an out-of-the-box solution and a quite simple tool, I think it's outdated and not flexible enough compared to the Spring IoC Container and Google Guice.*

Answer (score 1):

`ServiceLoader` is Java's light weight alternative to a full blown IoC container such as Spring, Guice, etc. It has far less bells and whistles than those frameworks, but works well for basic use cases when you just want to find what classes implement an interface.

Most application servers will have some usages of ServiceLoader you can see in practice:

https://github.com/apache/tomee/search?q=ServiceLoader&unscoped_q=ServiceLoader

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/search?q=ServiceLoader&unscoped_q=ServiceLoader

https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/search?q=ServiceLoader&unscoped_q=ServiceLoader

Comment: Thanks for the links. That helps a lot.

Comment: Sorry, the links became non active.

Answer (score -2):

When I hear something about `ServiceLoader`, the first thing, which comes to my mind, is `JDBC`. This technology provides loading JDBC driver classes from a classpath without using `Class.forName(Class<?>clazz)`.

Also, I am sure there are many examples of using `ServiceLoader`, beside **JDBC**